# How can I add a input box in a VS Code tree view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add input box in VS Code Tree View Extensions Development.
I don't want to open it in Command Palette.

Instead I wanted to open it in context menu as shown in Image[image: Image showing the input box implemented by vs code official file manager]

I also tried showInputBox Method.
But it opened in Command Palette
But I don't want it there, I want to open it in Context Menu

Comment: implement the whole thing in a `WebviewView`, search an HTML framework that does this and use that to create the `WebviewView`